# SVD of matrix plus diagonal matrix and inversed

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, svd

Assume we have a matrix $Z$ and we know its singular value decomposition. So, based on this, is there any trick for computing SVD of $(Z+cI)^{-1}$, where $cI$ is identity matrix, multiplied by some real-valued constant.

Thanks!

Comment: if i am not very tired, adding constant times the identity adds the constant to each eigenvalue and the eigenvectors stay the same. so the eigenvalues of $(Z+cI)^{-1}$ should be $(\lambda +c)^{-1}$ for each $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $Z$.

Comment: @mathreadler: Is that true when $Z \ (= U S V^T)$ is not symmetric? In the non-symmetric case, I think it's not true in general that $I = U [c  \cdot \text{diag}(1, \dots, 1)] V^T$.

Comment: @mathreadler: Eigenvalues are not singular values.

Comment: @copper.hat is right so the eigenvalue result is maybe not so useful.

Comment: I guess it will be $U(\Sigma + cI)^{-1}V^T$

Comment: It's a good guess but is it true? I can only see this holding if $I = UV^T$ but then $V^T = U^{-1}$ and $U^{-1} = U^T$ so $U^T=V^T$.